# Creating Image stacks and writing GDF file

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors

I am attempting to write a function that stack up series of images into image stack and converting it into a gdf file. I don't really know much about GDF files, so please help me out.

```
X=[];

for i=1:10

    if numel(num2str(i))==1
    X{i}=imread(strcat('0000',num2str(i),'.tif'));
    elseif numel(num2str(i))==2
    X{i}=imread(strcat('000',num2str(i),'.tif'));
    end
end

myImage=cat(3,X{1:10});
s=write_gdf('stack.gdf',myImage);
```

Above is to read my images labeled 00001 to 00010, all in grayscale. Everything is fine except in the last line

```
s=write_gdf('stack.gdf',myImage);
```

as when I run it, I receive an error:

```
Data type uint8 not supported
```

Any help on what this means? Should I convert it to some other colour format?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the code rather like this (I do not have `write_gdf` function so I can not properly test the code):

```
NumberOfFiles = 10;
X={};                 % preallocate CELL array
for n=1:NumberOfFiles % do not use "i" as your varable because it is imaginary unit in MatLab
    FileName = sprintf('%05d.tif',n);
    img      = imread(FileName); % load image
    X{i}     = double(img);      % and convert to desired format
end
myImage = cat(3,X{1:NumberOfFiles});
s = write_gdf('stack.gdf',myImage);
```

Keep in mind that

```
double(img);      % and convert to desired format
```

will not change data range. Your image even in `double` format will have data range from 0 to 255 if it was in `uint8` format on disk. If you need to normalize your data to 0..1 range you should do

```
X{i} = double(img)/255;
```

or in more unversal form

```
X{i} = double(img) / intmax(class(img));
```